# python Парсинг сайта

Tags: python, парсер

Есть  [сайт с картой города](https://map.novo-sibirsk.ru/), на котором можно посмотреть места и время отключения системы жизнеобеспечения города.

Мне нужно получить адреса домов в которых будет отключено электричество.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя проблема заключается в том, что насколько я понял, все данные о точках приходят в виде картинки png, которая накладывается поверх карты. Чисто теоретически, координаты домов можно получить и из этого, но если картинка будет охватывать весь город, то точки, помечающие дома, будут накладываться друг на друга и из-за этого определить координаты каждой будет невозможно.

Может я что-то пропустил, и есть другие способы получить координаты этих точек?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если ткнуть в точку, то появится окошко с адресом. Можно как-нибудь программным способом пройтись по всем видимым точкам.

Comment: @Эникейщик, слишком сложно и долго.